# Loading big data in Power Bi Api Semantic models - how to know that data are uploaded?

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I m loading Semantic models in power bi with help of power bi package in c#.
data sizes are big like 50 gb and I m loading those from Data Lake.

I m checking many documents but not able to find is there any way to keep user in no blocking mode and when those data will be loaded in to Semantic models.

we can notify user that all data are loaded some kind event or push or call back.

cos 50 gb data will take approx. 1 hour to load in to Semantic models.
and what I want to is when data is going to be completed load in Semantic models.
power bi will notify me by some event or call back...

for now I keep calling in pooling fashion to power bi about my data are loaded in Semantic models or not, I don't want to use pooling call to power bi and keep asking for Semantic models load done.

Any one have similar issue and suggestions?